# I just made a simple guessing game, but my 'remaining guesses' var isn't working

Tags: python, variables

I did a condition that if there's only one guess remaining, it shows 'one guess remaining', otherwise, it shows 'x guesses remaining".
But no matters if there's 1 guess remaining, the variable which decides the condition is always 3.

sorry for the English by the way.

```
import random

words = ("elephant", "giraffe", "dog", "cat", "turtle", "bird")
s_word = random.choice(words)
guess = ""
g_limit = 3
g_count = 0
out_of_g = False
g_remain = g_limit - g_count

while guess != s_word and not out_of_g:
    if g_count < g_limit:
        if g_remain < 2:
            print(str(g_remain) + " guesses remaining")
        else:
            print(str(g_remain) + " guess remaining")
        guess = input("enter a word: ")
        g_count += 1
    else:
        out_of_g = True

if out_of_g:
    print("you lose")
else:
    print("you won")
```

Answer (score 0):

The printouts will always show 3 guesses remaining because you don't update `g_remain`. You should do that after checking that the count is smaller than the limit:

```py
#...
while guess != s_word and not out_of_g:
    if g_count < g_limit:
        g_remain = g_limit - g_count # <------ UPDATE HERE
        if g_remain < 2:
            print(str(g_remain) + " guesses remaining")
        else:
            print(str(g_remain) + " guess remaining")
        guess = input("enter a word: ")
        g_count += 1
    else:
        out_of_g = True
#...
```

Or if you think further you might be able to get rid of eather `g_count`or `g_remain`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

words = ("elephant", "giraffe", "dog", "cat", "turtle", "bird")
s_word = random.choice(words)
guess = ""
g_limit = 3
g_count = 0
out_of_g = False
g_remain = g_limit - g_count

while guess != s_word and not out_of_g:
    if g_count < g_limit:
        if g_remain > 1:
            print(str(g_remain) + " guesses remaining")
            g_remain -= 1
        else:
            print(str(g_remain) + " guess remaining")
            g_remain -= 1
        guess = input("enter a word: ")
        g_count += 1
    else:
        out_of_g = True

if out_of_g:
    print("you lose")
else:
    print("you won")
```

Here is the solution. Change the if statement too, for correct version of 'guesses' and 'guess'.

Answer (score 0):

```
your code has too many unnecessary vars, we should fix it first

import random
words = ("elephant", "giraffe", "dog", "cat", "turtle", "bird")
s_word = random.choice(words)
guess = ""

g_count = 4
for guess in range(3):
    print(str(g_count - 1) + " guesses remaining")
    guess = input("enter a word: ")
    if guess == s_word:
        print('You Won')
        break
    else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

g_remain is set once. you have to update the value in every stage. here's the solution:

```
while guess != s_word and not out_of_g:
    g_remain = g_limit - g_count
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

You need to change only one line g_remian variable should be declare after while loop then only its works properly.

here is the code.

```
import random

words = ("elephant", "giraffe", "dog", "cat", "turtle", "bird")
s_word = random.choice(words)
guess = ""
g_limit = 3
g_count = 0
out_of_g = False

while guess != s_word and not out_of_g:
    g_remain = g_limit - g_count
    if g_count < g_limit:
        if g_remain < 2:
            print(str(g_remain) + " guesses remaining")
        else:
            print(str(g_remain) + " guess remaining")
        guess = input("enter a word: ")
        g_count += 1
    else:
        out_of_g = True

if out_of_g:
    print("you lose")
else:
    print("you won")
```